# Railsの数式はコントローラ、モデル、ビューどこに書くべきでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

唐突な質問で申し訳ありません。
以下の計算を行いたいのですが、数式はコントローラ、モデル、ビューどこに書くべきでしょうか？
テーブルには、仕入先A、仕入先B、仕入先C、売価、数量の5つのカラムの中にビューで入力した単価が入っています。

計算したい数式
1. (仕入先A + 仕入先B + 仕入先C) * 数量 = 原価合計
2. 売価 * 数量 = 売価合計
3. 売価合計 ÷ 原価合計 = 利益率
4. 売価合計 - 原価合計 = 利益額

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的な処理は全てModel内で行います。

たとえば2番の「売価 * 数量 = 売価合計」ですと

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sum_of_price
    price * number_of_stock
  end
end
```

のようにメソッド定義して、そのメソッドをViewから呼び出します。
実際には`price`や`number_of_stock`に値が`nil`でないかのチェックをした方がいいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！行いたい計算を行うことができました。

Comment: 1行目が「<<」と typo のようです。「<」ですよね。私が編集しようとしたら1文字の修正は許されないようです。(6文字以上っぽい)

Comment: @naopontan  指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。